# How to check location setting in real time in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, geolocation, ecmascript-2016

I am working on an application where I am checking that user is off or on their location. I am using `react-native-location-enabler` package to check the location setting, it works fine but the problem is it does not give me an updated state. For example, if I am off location from the top bar of the mobile it does not give me an updated result when I do refresh an app or close and open again it gives me the updated result. I want an updated result if the location is off from the top notification bar.

```
import LocationEnabler from "react-native-location-enabler";

const {
  PRIORITIES: { HIGH_ACCURACY },
  addListener,
  checkSettings,
  requestResolutionSettings,
  useLocationSettings,
} = LocationEnabler;

  const listener = addListener(({ locationEnabled }) =>
    console.log(`Location are ${locationEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"}`)
  );

  // Define configuration
  const config = {
    priority: HIGH_ACCURACY, // default BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
    alwaysShow: true, // default false
    needBle: false, // default false
  };

  // Check if location is enabled or not
  checkSettings(config);
```

Comment: I don't see how you are refreshing the state? Are you using hooks? Add more code or is this all the code?

Comment: This is a code, I really tried but was not able to find a solution. Do you have any code snippets on how to achieve the same functionality